# get the title of a relationship field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to set a custom post title with a custom field instead of typing the title im setting it with a custom field it works good if I use a type text custom field but once I use a relationship field Im getting nothing I guess because that field return a array, my relationship field is "route_affected_by_this_alert"

```
// Auto fill Title and Slug for CPT's - 'alerts'
function lh_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // Don't do this on the ACF post type
    // if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'project' ) {
    //     return;
    // }

    $new_title = '';
    $new_slug = '';
```

// Get title from 'alerts' CPT acf field 'route_affected_by_this_alert'
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts' ) {
$new_title =  get_field( 'route_affected_by_this_alert', $post_id );
$new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
}

```
    // Prevent iInfinite looping...
    remove_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post' );

    // Grab post data
    $post = array(
        'ID'            => $post_id,
        'post_title'    => $new_title,
        'post_name'     => $new_slug,
    );

    // Update the Post
    wp_update_post( $post );

    // Continue save action
    add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_save_post' );

    // Set the return URL in case of 'new' post
    $_POST['return'] = add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink( $post_id ) );
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 10, 1 );
```

I want to assign those names to the post title

[image: Want to get those names in the post title]

This is what im getting:

```
    Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 4009 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2020-05-22 11:29:55 [post_date_gmt] => 2020-05-22 15:29:55 [post_content] =>
Route 49 schedule - Effective 1/17/15
Kennedy Plaza Bus Stop Locations

[post_title] => Camp St/Miriam Hospital [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => 49 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2020-05-27 14:44:24 [post_modified_gmt] => 2020-05-27 18:44:24 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => https://mypage.com/?post_type=routes&p=4009 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => routes [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [1] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 4000 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2020-05-22 10:59:15 [post_date_gmt] => 2020-05-22 14:59:15 [post_content] =>
Route 60 schedule - Effective 1/19/19

Kennedy Plaza Bus Stop Locations

Newport Visitors Center Bus Stop Locations

All inbound and outbound trips service Bay View Apartments.

[post_title] => Providence/Newport [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => 60 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2020-06-08 11:02:14 [post_modified_gmt] => 2020-06-08 15:02:14 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => https://mypage.com/?post_type=routes&p=4000 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => routes [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) )
```

This is what im getting to make it work with the alerts CPT:
after: // generate our post title

```
// Code to get the title from a repeater field

function create_relationship_title($posts)
{

    // set empty net title array
    $new_title = [];

    // if posts is not an array then return false
    if (!is_array($posts)) return false;

    // loop through each post
    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        // add the current post title to new title array
        $new_title[] = $post->post_title;

    }

    // join all the related post titles together separated by a comma
    $new_title = implode(' AND ', $new_title);

    // return the new title
    return $new_title;

}



    function lh_acf_save_post($post_id ) {

    $new_title = '';

    // Get title from 'alerts' CPT acf field 'route_affected_by_this_alert'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts' ) {
        $relationships = get_field( 'route_affected_by_this_alert', $post_id );
        $new_title = create_relationship_title($relationships);
    }

    // get our product object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // generate our post title
    if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts') {

        // remove the action
        remove_action('acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20);

        // update the post object
        $post->post_title = $new_title;
        $post->post_name = sanitize_title($new_title);

        // update post
        wp_update_post($post);

        // re add the action
        add_action('acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20);

    }

    // finally, return
    return;

}

  
   

// construct your action here
 add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated version...

```
<?php

/**
 * @param $posts array
 * @return false|string
 */
function create_relationship_title($posts)
{

    // set empty net title array
    $new_title = [];

    // if posts is not an array then return false
    if (!is_array($posts)) return false;

    // loop through each post
    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        // add the current post title to new title array
        $new_title[] = $post->post_title;

    }

    // join all the related post titles together separated by a comma
    $new_title = implode(', ', $new_title);

    // return the new title
    return $new_title;

}

/**
 * @param $post_id int
 */
function lh_acf_save_post($post_id ) {

    // check we are on the correct post type
    if(get_post_type($post_id) <> 'alerts') return;

    $new_title = '';

    // Get title from 'companies' CPT acf field 'company_name'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts' ) {
        $relationships = get_field( 'route_affected_by_this_alert', $post_id );
        $new_title = create_relationship_title($relationships);
    }

    // get our product object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // generate our post title
    if($post->post_status == 'publish' || $post->post_status == 'draft') {

        // remove the action
        remove_action('acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20);

        // update the post object
        $post->post_title = $new_title;
        $post->post_name = sanitize_title($new_title);

        // update post
        wp_update_post($post);

        // re add the action
        add_action('acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20);

    }

    // finally, return
    return;

}

// construct your action here
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'lh_acf_save_post', 20 );
```

Comment: I just re-read your question and I miss understood about the relationship field, i've not seen any code from your  `relationship` field array so I'm not sure how to answer

Comment: Thank for answering my friend, Basically what I want is to get the title of a post from a relationship field instead of typing it, I have a custom field type "Relationship" its name is "route_affected_by_this_alert" im adding some posts to that field hoping to get the title and assign it to the post that Im creating, if I use a field type text I can get the title but I dont know how to get the title using a Relationship.

Comment: Can you `echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_field( 'route_affected_by_this_alert', $post_id )).'</pre>'; exit;` and let me know what is returned. Also in the acf relationship field options you can set the field to return the id or the object. Let me know what is returned and i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering my friend I set the relationship post to "post object"  when I created it, I put the print_r and im getting this (this is a part): Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 4009 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2020-05-22 11:29:55 [post_date_gmt] => 2020-05-22 15:29:55 [post_content] =>
Route 49 schedule - Effective 1/17/15
Kennedy Plaza Bus Stop Locations

[post_title] => Camp St/Miriam Hospital [post_excerpt] => (I want to assign the titles to my post)

Comment: Can you add the full `print_r` output to your question. So am I right in thinking there can be more than one relationship, as in you can select multiple items. And would you like to join all these `post_titles` together separated by a comma or something?

Comment: I put it in my question as you said, thats exactly what I want my friend the name of the post is the same of the items added in the relationship, so I have to type it. as you said I want to assign the title items to my title post. thank you

Comment: Updated answer, let me know if that is what you are after

Comment: My friend it works perfect, thank you very much I appreciated a lot your help, you´re a genius! Can I reach out to you for future questions?

Comment: Hello my friend for some reason that code is applying to all the site and custom post types, pages, posts any idea? thank you

Comment: I added this to in //generate our post title//  // generate our post title
    if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts') it works do you think is is the wrong way? or have a better idea?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What did you add into it?

Comment: It works perfect in my local host in a different site the code is perfect, but once I put it in another site its basically the same site the code applies to all my custom post types and post, if I create a page or post that pages or post tries to get the title from a relationship that does not exist so instead of adding a title, it goes blank so Instead of if($post->post_status == 'publish' || $post->post_status == 'draft') {  I added if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alerts') { and it looks like its working in the site, do you think thats correct? I updated the question thank you very much

Comment: I've just updated code with `if(get_post_type($post_id) <> 'product') return;`

Comment: It works perfect, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a function...

```
$my_query = get_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
   'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'relationship_field_name', 
           'value' => get_the_ID(), 
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

foreach( $my_query as $object ):
    print_r($object); //you'll see everything about the single post
    
    $object_title = $object->post_title; //title
    $object_acf_field = get_field('acf_field_name',$object->ID); //any ACF field
endforeach;
```